# MultiStep form help

Tags: 7

I am creating multistep form

I created a custom module for this.

My problem is this is not rebuliding form. it just appending to first form

Here is my code

```
function security_questions_form_tenantwallet_trouble_logging_in_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if(isset($form_state['input']['problem_signup']) && ($form_state['input']['problem_signup'] == 'reset_password')){
      // Abort if the password form is not protected.
          if (!variable_get('security_questions_trouble_login', FALSE)) {
            return;
          }
          global $user;

          // We need our own submission handler to make this a multistep form.
          $form['#submit'] = array('security_questions_tenantwallet_trouble_logging_in_form_submit');

          // If the user is already logged in but not allowed to bypass, or our submit
          // handler triggered a rebuild, then we need to issue a challenge.
          $account = FALSE;
          if ($user->uid > 0 && !security_questions_bypass_challenge($user)) {
            $account = $user;
          }
          elseif (!empty($form_state['security_questions']['uid'])) {
            $account = user_load($form_state['security_questions']['uid']);
          }
          if ($account) {
            $form += security_questions_challenge($account);
           $form['#validate'] = array_merge(array('security_questions_set_login_timestamp'), $form['#validate']);
            $form['#validate'][] = 'security_questions_tenantwallet_trouble_logging_in_form_answer_validate';
            $form['name']['#type'] = 'value';
            $form['name']['#value'] = $account->mail;
            //$form['values']['#account'] = user_load_by_mail($account->mail);
          }
    }
}
```

and submit function is

```
function security_questions_tenantwallet_trouble_logging_in_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // If the user is allowed to bypass or has already answered the challenge,
  // hand off to the normal password reset submission handler.
//print_r($form_state);
  //$account = $form_state['values'];
    $account = user_load_by_mail($form_state['input']['mail']);

//tenantwallet_trouble_logging_in_form_submit($form, $form_state);
  if (security_questions_bypass_challenge($account) || !empty($form_state['security_questions']['passed_challenge'])) {
//echo 'submit hiiii';exit;
    //user_pass_submit($form, $form_state);
    tenantwallet_trouble_logging_in_form_submit($form, $form_state);
  }
  // Otherwise, store the ID of the user requesting the reset and rebuild.
  else {

//echo 'submit bye';
    $form_state['security_questions']['uid'] = $account->uid;
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  }
}
```

Does anybody have idea. regarding this 
Thanks

Comment: Hello. I suggest you to try to make question's title more distinctive. There are dozens of questions about multistep forms here, so it's less likely to catch an eye of someone who can answer.