# Multi-step form in Drupal 8 using Ctools

Tags: 8, forms

I am looking at examples and code out there for multi-page (multistep) forms in Drupal 8, and it seems there are two ways of approaching this:

- Using raw Form API [This Sitepoint tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-multi-step-forms-in-drupal-8/)
- [Chaos tools](https://www.drupal.org/node/2468609)

I have not had much experience with using ctools, but I would prefer to use the simpler method, problem is that I do not understand how to use the ctools wizard to create a multipage form.

[This issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/196504/6488) started me off in the CTools direction, but the only example I have is the tests, and I am struggling!

Comment: Just want to throw it out there that Webform now does multi page forms.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin I have ended up using Webform module, I didn't realize just how fully featured it is in D8!